# angular material menu-bar demo not reproducible

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

the angular md-menu-bar demo shows a nested Menu under new. Check the code from the demo on codepen here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.menuBar

As you can see, from the codepen, the nested menu opens on hover, but in the HTML you can see the button element has a ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()" function. I cannot see how to this even works. Am also failing to get the side arrow to appear for the submenu.

Are people able to replicate this demo? My code is a follows:

```
   md-menu-bar
      md-menu(md-position-mode="target-right target", md-offset="0 40", width="4")
        button.ts-chart-icon.refresh-icon.glyphicon.glyphicon-certificate(ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()", md-menu-origin)
          md-tooltip(md-delay="0") Add Overlay
        md-menu-content.ts-menu-content(width="5")
          md-menu-item(md-menu-align-target)
            md-button(disabled="disabled", ng-if="!chartConfig.series") Add 50D Moving Average
            md-menu.nested-menu(ng-if="chartConfig.series")
              md-button(ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()") Add 50D Moving Average
              md-menu-content(ng-show="chartConfig.series", width="5")
                md-menu-item(ng-repeat="s in chartConfig.series")
                  md-button(ng-click="handleAdd50DMA_(s)") {{ s.name }}
```

Comment: Can you create codepen of your work?

Comment: Not easily no - part of a larger project. Would be helpful to know though how the nested menu is opening on hover at the very least when the click attribute is specified

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from angular-material 0.10.1 to 0.11 and it is working fine now.